# Render layout preview failed in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

I'm using *Android Studio 2.3.3 - Build #AI-162.4069837* and my `build.gradle` dependency block is :

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

When I try to preview layout in design mode, the view does not render in all layouts that use `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` and `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` or ... give the following error-

> the following classes could not be instantiated

I did clean and rebuild project, clear cache, close and reopen *Android Studio*, but did not solve the problem.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ViewBackgroundHelper
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatBackgroundHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatBackgroundHelper.java:46)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:63)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:475)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:262)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:213)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:193)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:333)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:152)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:222)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:95)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.NavigationBar.<init>(NavigationBar.java:52)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.NavigationBar.<init>(NavigationBar.java:46)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createNavBar(Layout.java:284)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:140)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:301)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:567)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:549)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:680)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your project level build.gradle dependency to this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

And replace your app level gradle dependencies with these versions

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.+'
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41584688/6699069) answer might be related to your problem

Edit: Seems you are not alone. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134107/android-studio-2-3-beta-1-support-25-1-0-preview-broken/41584688#41584688) and [this](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues/353) post, the solution was to wait for next update or disable cache in gradle.properties Some people have rolled back to stable gradle and support library versions as a temporary solution.

Comment: thanks, project level is `2.3.3` and when use `+` , not effected and don't resolve problem.
<br>
it worked so far add `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm` library to dependency.

Comment: The latest support library version is 26.1.0. Replace all 26.+ to 26.1.0 and sync project. If you get any sync error, update sdk and retry

Comment: Did you try "Invalidate cache and restart" after changing build.gradle lib versions to 26.1.0 ?

Comment: updated answer. Try disabling cache in gradle.properties. Visit third link for instructions

Answer (score 0):

Changing the theme from Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar to Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar in styles.xml has worked for me.